# Splitting value items in a dictionary

Tags: c#, split, idictionary

I asked a similar question before but am just asking it from a slightly different angle.

I have a list of codes and underneath each code I have a bunch of values that are taken from the fields Subject and GenSubject.

Problem is these values(especially the general subjects) contain various elements, seperated by ';'. How can I incorperate the split function within the dictionary as to split the various values as I run the query?

```
while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                string code = (string)dbReader["CODE"];
                string subject = (string)dbReader["SUBJECT"];
                string generalSublject = (string)dbReader["GenSubject"];


                dict.Add(code, new List<string> { subject,generalSublject });


            }
```

This is the result of which I want to split the values wherever they need splitting.

[image]

(I want to split the values before adding them to the dictionary)

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to split before adding to dictionary? Or after?

Comment: Before adding the values to the dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split the `generalSublject` string and create the list based on it, then insert the `subject` as the first item.

```
var list = new List<string>(generalSublject.Split(new string[] { ";" },
    StringSplitOptions.None));
list.Insert(0, subject);
dict.Add(code, list);
```